# C# - Windows Form Localization (language) change during runtime - ListView column headers won't change language

Tags: c#, listview, localization, runtime

I am currently working on a project that must support 6 different languages. I already have a working implementation using resource files for strings and form localization for controls. The final part of the implementation involves changing the language in real time while the program is running. I have seen advice of how to do this, and I ended up using a modified version of the ApplyResources method. In general, I'm talking about this kind of thing:

```
ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

resources.ApplyResources(_mybutton, _mybutton.Name, culture);
```

Thus, the button "_mybutton" text would then get changed to the French localized version. This is working for all of my forms and controls, EXCEPT for a particular ListView control. This ListView has 5 columns of object type ColumnHeader. I am trying to change the text of the column headers to the new language using ApplyResources. I have already added the appropriate French text in the .fr.resx resource file for the column headers, and the Designer View is showing me the French translated version when I switch the form localization to French, just as expected.

Even further, I tried changing the global thread currentUICulture property to French before the form's InitializeComponent() method in the constructor. I verified that this will load the correct French resources for the column headers in the list view.

However, my problem arises when I try to manually apply a culture to the ColumnHeader/ListView resources. For example I will say the code looks approximately like this:

```
ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(myUserControl));
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); 
resources.ApplyResources(_myListView, _myListView.Name, culture);
resources.ApplyResources(_myColumnHeader1, _myColumnHeader1.Name, culture);
this.Refresh();
```

No matter what I try, I can't get the French resources to be applied to the column header text. I also tried:

```
 resources.ApplyResources(_myListView.Columns[0], _myListView.Columns[0].Name, culture);
```

And I tried something similar after searching for solutions on stackoverflow:

```
 var lv = (ListView)_myListView;
 foreach (ColumnHeader col in lv.Columns)
 {
     resources.ApplyResources(col, col.Name, culture);
 }
```

Same effect - no language change. I looked at the Designer.cs code to see if there was any critical difference or line I was missing and it looks like I am doing it correctly. All of the other controls change language correctly but the column headers in my listview refuse to change text dynamically. Has anyone seen this before? What am I doing wrong here?

In the very worst case, I can just move the text for the column headers to the external resource files and then manually set the text of each column header, but I find that to be a big hassle, especially if I have to deal with listviews later that have many columns, or if the text needs to have multiple values for each language. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I did more research into my own question and it appears there is actually a bug in the .NET Framework in that the .Name method of ColumnHeader objects does not actually return the object name correctly. This is why my attempts to apply resources to the object failed.

I was able to fix the problem by hardcoding the changes for the ColumnHeaders. For example:

```
resources.ApplyResources(_myHeader, "_myHeader", culture);
```

You basically just replace the call to .Name with a literal string of the name. I have tested this and it works. Unfortunately this means it won't fit as part of the code I use to change all of the controls. I have to add a line for each ColumnHeader object I need to change. Fortunately I am not using a listview with a variable number of columns, because that could get tricky.

Another option is to create localized resource files. You probably already have them for stuff like message box text and other strings. Then you can add an entry in your resource file like "columnHeader_myHeader" and set the appropriate language text for each language. Finally, you can manually change the text to your column headers by using:

```
_myHeader.Text = myResourceFileName.columnHeader_myHeader;
```

This will select the appropriate language based on the current thread culture.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Name Attribute for a column Header still does not showup the Name of the column Header. Like this, Looping through all columns doesn't work:

```
foreach (ColumnHeader col in lv.Columns)
{
     resources.ApplyResources(col, col.Name, culture);
}
```